# How to remove all default styling in jquery validation error message?

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

How can I remove all default styling from error message?
I need this document structure:

```
  <div class="error">
    <p>error message</p>
  </div>
```

I'm using this javascript

```
      errorElement: "p",
      wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element)
        error.addClass('error');  // add a class to the wrapper
```

But getting

```
   <div class="error">
     <p class="error">error message</p>
   </div>
```

It also adds error class to input, which I don't need,
How can I remove error class from paragraph and input?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div p.error').removeClass('error');
```

Comment: Where do I need to put it? Do I need to insert this line to <script> tag?

Comment: well yes and no :) u will need jquery google it, jquery is a javascript library that makes it easier to use javascript. its only one file called jquery core and then you put that on a script tag.